# Ultrasonic Sensor reading problem in arduino

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I am using Arduino uno and Ultrasonic sensor to measure distance of an object . When i connect usb from my laptop to the arduino , it works fine . But when i remove the USB and connect external power to the Arduino , the Tx and Rx on Arduino does not work and it just uses the previous distance . I don't understand the problem . Is it a power supply problem ?

```
const int pingPin = 11; // Trigger Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor
const int echoPin = 12; // Echo Pin of Ultrasonic Sensor
const int ml1=8;
const int ml2=7;
const int mr1=10;
const int mr2=9;
void setup() {
  pinMode(ml1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ml2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mr1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mr2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starting Serial Terminal
 }

 void loop() {
   long duration;
   long distance;
   digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(2);
   digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(10);
   digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
   duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
   distance=duration*0.034/2;
   Serial.print(distance);
   Serial.print("cm");
   Serial.println();
  if(distance>8)
   {
    digitalWrite(ml1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ml2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(mr1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(mr2,HIGH);
    }
  else{
   digitalWrite(ml1,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(ml2,LOW);
   digitalWrite(mr1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(mr2,HIGH);
   delay(1000);
   digitalWrite(ml1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(ml2,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(mr1,LOW);
   digitalWrite(mr2,HIGH);

   }


   }
```

it's actually a obstacle avoider bot and according to the object distance the bot runs away . But as i said before it does not get the sensor reading when i remove the usb .

Comment: `But when i remove the USB...` how do you physically connect the serial out of the Arduino to the PC?

Comment: i don't connect physically after removing the USB . I use the sensor data to drive the mototr auomatically .

Comment: I'm confused. Where do you expect to see the output of the `Serial.println()` stuff? Serial ports are not wireless. You need a cable between the Arduino and the PC to use Serial.

Comment: Well ..Serial.println() is for checking only on the arduino ide monitor . It's not necessery to run the bot . I just need the distance value . Now is that causing problem when i removed the usb ?

Comment: So, the bot works ok when connected to the pc, but malfunctions when disconnected? (Also, you might want to delete this question and ask at [arduino.se].)

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem .

Comment: OK. I don't see the issue. Are you sure your power supply provides enough current?

Comment: Yes i am sure about that

Comment: Typically, USB provides an additional GND connection. But your question does not provide any electrical circuit information, Nor is this the proper forum for such questions.